# What are the best practices/setup for applying caching techniques in web application?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I want to apply caching techniques to improve my asp.net web application performance. I am going to use .NET default cash. I want to store the data in the XML file as well so that If the system fails to found the data from the cache, I can use the XML file as a secondary option. Is this workflow seems well or standard? Will file i/o operation degrade the performance instead of improving it or break the system integrity? The data volume will be medium and the number of files will be around 1k~2k.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML files as data source seems like a rather unorthodox approach. A more common way would be using a [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) as data source and something like the [Distributed Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#distributed-redis-cache) for caching.
See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for further information.

Comment: I know redis cache is a common option, I wanted to know what is the best way to implement that in an enterprise level web application